# Smoothing a Function with multiple Curves

Tags: python

I have a function that I wanted to graph, but it has multiple curves so I cannot use curve fitting and I dont know how to smooth it ? Any help

Here is my Code

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Int = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0,0,0.02,0.32,0.04,0,0,0.18,0.78,
0.76,0.2,0,0,0.3,0.3,0.1,0,0,0.04,0,0.06,0.0,0,0,0,0]
Angle = [i for i in range(-85,90,5)]
x = Angle
y = Int

plt.plot(x,y,"r")
plt.xlabel("Angle")
plt.ylabel("Intensity (mA)")
plt.title("Intensity vs Angle")
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='r', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are looking for "signal filtering": https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it, I find a youtube video ..

Here the new code and I wanted to graph it like this

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
import numpy as np

Int = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0,0,0.02,0.32,0.04,0,0,0.18,0.78,
0.76,0.2,0,0,0.3,0.3,0.1,0,0,0.04,0,0.06,0.0,0,0,0,0])
Angle = np.array([i for i in range(-85,90,5)])
x = Angle
y = Int

x_smooth=np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),300)

spl = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=3)
y_smooth = spl(x_smooth)

plt.plot(x_smooth,y_smooth)




plt.xlabel("Angle")
plt.ylabel("Intensity (mA)")
plt.title("Intensity vs Angle")
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='-')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='r', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.show()
```

But thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In `scipy.signals` you will find different techniques of signal preprocessing and filtering.

One easy filter is the Savitzky-Golay-Filter: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter

It browses through your data with a moving window, i.e. looking n values back and n values ahead of its position. The farer away a point from the target point, the less influence it has on the smoothing. The size of your window is specified by `window_length` and the intensity in the decrease in distance by the `polyorder`.

Add this piece of code before your plotting section:

```
import scipy.signal
y_filtered = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(x=y, window_length=3, polyorder=1)
plt.plot(x,y_filtered,"b")
```

Play around with window_length and polyorder. Note that polyorder must be smaller than window_length and that higher window_lengths may clip your data heavily.

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: It doesnt seem to work well. I mean it gives me the similar curve and with low values which its not good..

Comment: Please be specific. What is your desired outcome? The image in my answer shows an appropriate smoothing of your curve. The peak is lower because that's what smoothing does.